# Two dataframes with 'isin()' only returning TRUE/FALSE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

After searching online and similar questions, it seems that there are many questions on this, but difficult to find a case that applies to my problem.

Columns of `df_a` contains many columns, one of which is `x`.
`df_b` also has the column `x`.

So I have the following code (and variations aa, bb, cc, dd -- all work)

```
aa = df_a['x'].isin(df_b['x'])
bb = df_a[['x']].isin(df_b['x'])
cc = df_a['x'].isin(df_b[['x']])
dd = df_a[['x']].isin(df_b[['x']])
```

Main problem: this only returns a vector of True/False. I would like for it to return all of `df_a` columns with only the rows filtered with True values. What do I need for this?

Comment: Can you add some small data sample and expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
aa = df_a[df_a['x'].isin(df_b['x'])].copy()
```